# how to use the combinations of k elements of n (binomial coefficients) in a formula

Tags: summation, notation, combinations, binomial-coefficients

Let's assume set $$S = (2,3,4,5)$$
I like to express the sum of the products of all possible unique combinations of $k$ (distinct) elements of $S$. I know the binomial coefficient is equal to:

$${\displaystyle {n \choose k}={\frac {n!}{k!(n-k)!}} }$$

I want to represent the following summations in a more general mathematical formula:

$$X_1 = (2) + (3) + (4) + (5) $$
$$X_2 = (2 . 3) + (2 . 4) + (2 . 5) + (3 . 4) + (3 . 5) + (4 . 5)$$
$$X_3 = (2 . 3 . 4) + (2 . 3 . 5) + (2 . 4 . 5) + (3 . 4 . 5)$$
$$X_4 = (2 . 3 . 4 . 5)$$

My best try is:

$$X_k = \sum_{i}^{k} S_i . \dots . S_k$$

It doesn't feel right... Anyone who can help me?

Comment: Generating functions will let you use $f(x)=(1+2x)(1+3x)(1+4x)(1+5x),$ and the coefficient of $x^k$ in $f(x)$ is the value you want.  But I doubt there is a good formula for such a value.

Comment: You can write it as $$\sum_{T\subseteq S, |T|=k}\prod_{t\in T} t$$ That assumes you are dealing with sets of distinct values. If $S=(s_i)_{i=1}^n$ might contain repeated values, you can instead write it as $$\sum_{J\subseteq\{1,2,\dots,n\},|J|=k}\prod_{j\in J} s_j$$

Comment: If you define  things properly,  you can simplify that  as $J\in \binom{[n]}k$ to mean $J$ is a $k$-subset of $[n]=\{1,2,\dots,n\}.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thx! In my use case S doesn't contain repeated values. So I will use the first one.